# A client and a server, how should I validate a user when he logs in?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, validation

The current situation is that I have two separate applications.

One is the one I called *user_client* and the other is the server.

The user_client is mostly the "mark-up", [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) stuff. This application will just throw a request to the server and receive a response. That's all.

On the other hand, the server is a [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) installation, where its *controllers* will receive a request thrown by the *client*, process the data and send back a response.

But I am rather confused on how to I validate a user and where to store their sessions.

The problem now is that I have a login form in the user_client, and I setup JavaScript code to do Ajax calls to the server.

Something like:

```
success : server_path + 'login',
```

What I have done so far is that I used the data sent by the Ajax call to the server to validate the user and save a session.

I am doing it right? When I saved a session, it is a session of the server, right? Not the user_client.

And how do I check if the user is logged in? Is it still possible to do the following?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['whatever']))
```

What am I missing out about sessions? What are my misconceptions about sessions, because I believe there are.

Comment: If you are using sessions then the client has to be using cookies. The other way to do it is generate a "token" on the server, typically a random string, and save that to server database. you pass the token to client, either in a hidden form field or the url string, and then the token is passed back when they submit a form or click on a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session (simplified) is just a way for the server to keep track of one particular user across page requests. CI sessions will keep track of the user by creating a cookie on the client browser that saves a session id - that session id (if set up to) will be saved in the database in the "ci_sessions" (default name) table. All session data will be saved there.

Doing it the way you suggest is fine, just be sure to use a secure connection when you pass the authentication to the server.